# jQuery Drag/Drop problem: mousemove Event not binding for some elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable, drag-and-drop

Using the latest jQuery/UI that are hosted at Google.  I've got the following markup:

```
<ul id="tree">
    <li><a href="1/">One</a></li>
<li><a href="2/">Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Droppable callbacks
function dragOver(overEvent, ui_object) {
    $(this).mousemove(function(moveEvent){
        console.log("moved over", this);
    });
}

function drop_deactivate() {
    $(this).unbind();
}

function drag_out() {
    $(this).unbind();
}

// Actual dragging
$("#treeContainer li").draggable({
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 0
});

// Actuall dropping
$("a").droppable({
    tolerance: "pointer",
    over: dragOver,
    deactivate: drop_deactivate,
    out: drag_out
});
```

});

If I drag the first `li` down over the second, the mousemove function fires (and firebug logs the output).  But if I drag the second `li` up over the first, the mousemove function doesn't fire.  You can see this live at http://jsbin.com/ivala.  Is there a reason for this?  Should I be trapping the mousemove event in some other way?

Edit:  It appears as thought the mousemove() event isn't binding for earlier elements than the one currently being dragged (should be bound upon their mouseover).

Comment: I opened the link and sometimes dragging the second li up over the first firebug logs the output. But it's much more easier dragging the first up over the second.

Comment: I've noticed that too.  It's not regualr behavior; very puzzling.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by adding the mousemove event?

Comment: I want to know where the mouse cursor is relative to the element, top/middle/bottom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears the draggable's helper element is eating the mouse move events.  If the cursor is over the helper the container underneath will not receive mousemove events.

Try to position the helper offset from the cursor so the cursor never has the helper element directly underneath it.  You can do this with draggable's cursorAt option:

`draggable({ cursorAt: { top: 5, left: 5 } })`

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, even though it's been > 24 months since I asked and now have absolutely NO IDEA why I needed this.

Comment: :) Thanks.  I had a similar issue and figured this probably fixes it and explains the intermittent behavior you were noticing (for example, the mouse moving faster than the drag helper, causing some mouse move events before the helper catches up to the mouse).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have done and it works.

```
$(dragMe).draggable({ 
   start : function(e){
             $(this).css({'pointer-events': 'none'});
         }, 
   stop: function(e){
             $(this).css({'pointer-events': 'all'});
         }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either try to add the pointerEvents CSS style to your helper. That way, all events would pass though the dragged element.

```
clone.css('pointerEvents', 'none');
```

With the full draggable stuff:

```
element.draggable({
    helper: function() {
        var clone = element.clone();
        clone.css('pointerEvents', 'none');
        return clone;
    }
})
```